# Stripe - As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway to one of our existing projects and got the below message
while testing , Below is the screenshot

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28G3G.png)

This is a fully functional code downloaded from the Stripe Repo

https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js

Found the below link , However it did not help

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/327

Would appreciate if anyone could let me know if we have any workarounds by any chance for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports#export-of-services

Comment: @pqnet , I've referred to the documentation , However had challenges understanding it.
I am using this only for the purpose of testing.

Do I have to register my organisation to use their services?  Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to Stripe's support team directly via https://support.stripe.com/email if, after following their docs, you're still running into issues. They'll be able to verify if your account needs anything added in order to test out this functionality.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Thanks! , I've sent them an email , we'll see what they have to say